# AOP Spring Before Advice not working

Tags: spring, aop

The method DefaultProduitGeneriqueService.valider is not catched by the method traceWhenReturnedValueDoesntExistOrNotNecessary and I don't understand why?

```
package fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.impl;

public class DefaultProduitGeneriqueService extends DefaultService implements IProduitGeneriqueService, IBacAware {

...

@Override
@Traceable(value = ETraceableMessages.VALIDATION_PRODUIT_GENERIQUE, hasReturnedValue=Traceable.HAS_NOT_RETURNS_VALUE)
public void valider(ElementNiveauUn element) {
   ...
}
...
}

package fr.generali.nova.atp.logging.advisor;


@Aspect
public class TraceableAdvisor {

    @Before(value = "execution(* fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.impl.*.*(..)) && @annotation(traceable) && args(element)", argNames = "element,traceable")
    public void traceWhenReturnedValueDoesntExistOrNotNecessary(ElementNiveauUn element, Traceable traceable) {
       ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `DefaultProduitGeneriqueService` a Spring bean? Spring AOP can only be applied to beans.

Comment: Is DefaultProduitGeneriqueService is a bean

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both beans are properly configured, either through annotations or in your `appCtx`.

It looks like your Aspect is definitely right, but how about the other class?  Is it Spring enabled?

Also, if both classes are indeed configured correctly, are you sure that the instance being passed is a Spring bean and not a "new" instance from a constructor?

Comment: Also make sure that the bean's aspect-annotated methods are always accessed through a handle provided by Spring, and never through `this`. (Or switch to using full AspectJ, which does bytecode mods instead of using proxies.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the service interfaces are in package **`fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.api`**:

```
package fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.api;

public interface IProduitGeneriqueService {

    void valider(ElementNiveauUn element);
}
```

And the service implementations are in package **`fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.impl`**:

```
package fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.impl;

public class DefaultProduitGeneriqueServiceImpl implements IProduitGeneriqueService {

    @Override
    @Traceable(value = ETraceableMessages.VALIDATION_PRODUIT_GENERIQUE, hasReturnedValue=Traceable.HAS_NOT_RETURNS_VALUE)
    public void valider(ElementNiveauUn element) {
        // TODO: implement
    }
}
```

Your aspect should look like this:

```
package fr.generali.nova.atp.logging.advisor;

@Aspect
public class TraceableAdvisor {

    @Before(value = "execution(* fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.api.*.*(..)) && @annotation(traceable) && args(element)", argNames = "element,traceable")
    public void traceWhenReturnedValueDoesntExistOrNotNecessary(ElementNiveauUn element, Traceable traceable) {
         // TODO: implement
        System.err.println("traced...");
    }
}
```

The default proxy strategy for Spring AOP is JDK interface-based proxies<del>, so Your pointcut expression should match the **interface method execution**, not the implementation method execution</del>, and Your poincut expression may match either interface mothod execution or implementation method execution.

And remember to include an `AspectJAutoProxyCreator` in your configuration using for example `<aspectj-autoproxy />` tag.

And here is a simple test to prove everyting is working:

```
public class TraceableAdvisorTest {

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public IProduitGeneriqueService produitGeneriqueService() {
            return new DefaultProduitGeneriqueServiceImpl();
        }

        @Bean
        public TraceableAdvisor traceableAdvisor() {
            return new TraceableAdvisor();
        }

        @Bean
        public AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator autoProxyCreator() {
            return new AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator();
        }
    }

    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext testApplicationContext;

    @Test
    public void testTraceWhenReturnedValueDoesntExistOrNotNecessary() {
        this.testApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        this.testApplicationContext.register(TestConfiguration.class);
        this.testApplicationContext.refresh();

        IProduitGeneriqueService service = BeanFactoryUtils.beanOfType(this.testApplicationContext, IProduitGeneriqueService.class);

        System.err.println("BEFORE");
        service.valider(null);
        System.err.println("AFTER");
    }
}
```

The `err` output is:

```
BEFORE
traced...
AFTER
```

For all combinations:

- `fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.api.*.*(..)`
- `fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.impl.*.*(..)`
- `fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier..*.*(..)`

Comment: the IProduitGeneriqueService is in fr.generali.nova.atp.service.api package. I replace impl by * in pointcut like that     @Before(value = "execution(* fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.*.*.*(..)) && @annotation(traceable) && args(element)", argNames = "element,traceable")

Comment: So in Your case it should be: `execution(* fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.api..*.*(..))` - meaning execution of every method (this part: `.*(..)`) in every class (the first: `.*`) in any subpackage of `fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.api` (the part: `fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.api..` - **NOTE double dot in the end**).

Comment: @Roadrunner: *so your pointcut expression should intercept the interface method calls, not the implementation method calls* Wrong!!! The JDK proxies are created by interpreting the Pointcuts on the actual bean classes.

Comment: If You use naming convensions for Your service interfaces I'd suggest: `execution(* fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.api..I*Service.*(..))` to catch only the ones that start with `I` and end with `Service`.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: _The JDK proxies are created by interpreting the Pointcuts on the actual bean classes_ - yes, but using AOP with JDK proxies You can only intercept methods that are declared in the interfaces implemented by that actual bean and that's why you write poincut expressions to match Your interfaces, not Your implementations. @See: [this reference page](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-common-pointcuts) for example @Pointcut `businessService()` ant it's comment.

Comment: @Roadrunner you have missed something: "This definition assumes that interfaces are placed in the "dao" package, **and that implementation types are in sub-packages**." These pointcuts match implementation classes, **not** interfaces

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: I think I got it all right. The test I added to the answer proves it.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: OK, maybe not all... It turns out that all the combinations: `fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.api.*.*(..)`, `fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier.impl.*.*(..)` and `fr.generali.nova.atp.service.metier..*.*(..)` make the test pass with the same output. Anyway I've always matched interfaces and it always worked for me.